# Как сделать вот такую рамку?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Рамка должна выглядеть как на скриншоте

[image: пикч1]

Вот максимум, что получилось  у меня

[image: пикч2]

```
.button {
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 100;
color: rgb(192, 189, 189);
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-image: 
  linear-gradient(
  to top, 
  #336699, 
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
  ) 1 100%;

padding: 15px 25px;
margin-top: 85px;
}
```

Comment: svg Вас не устрвивает?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: #111;
}

.button {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: rgb(192, 189, 189);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px white;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.button:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px white;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.border-top {
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #369, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1;
}

.border-bottom {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #369, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1;
}

.border-left {
  border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to top, #369, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1;
}

.border-right {
  border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #369, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="border-top">
    <div class="border-bottom">
      <div class="border-left">
        <div class="border-right">
          <button class="button">Начать путешествие</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 15):

#### Не кнопка, а просто космос!

*Усаживаемся в кресле поудобнее, жмём волшебную кнопку и слушаем приятную мелодию Magic Fly, Space 1977 года, релаксируем и получаем удовольствие. Приятного отдыха! :)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function playSound(sound) {
  var song = document.getElementById(sound);
  song.volume = 1;
  if (song.paused) {
    song.play();
  } else {
    song.pause();
  }
}

function classToggle() {
  ico.classList.toggle('i__play');
  ico.classList.toggle('i__pause');
  active.classList.toggle('div');
  active.classList.toggle('div__active');
}
var active = document.querySelector('.div');
var ico = document.querySelector('i');
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', classToggle);

var grounds = [
  'https://inteleqtika.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/5f8f7315229a10640a4319bb244ca199.jpg',
  'https://img1.akspic.ru/image/25765-windows_10-vselennaya-zemlya-kosmicheskoe_prostranstvo-microsoft_windows-2048x1152.jpg', 'https://static.tumblr.com/384288505793149ce71fbdbfc0eb33ee/yzamvjg/JVBoxhk02/tumblr_static_6sewy9zjfeccck0o8w048ggcs.jpg',
  'https://versiya.info/uploads/posts/2018-11/1543574439_interesnye-fakty-vselennaya-778143.jpeg'
];
var index = 0;
var t = 1;
var len = grounds.length;
var div = $('.div');
(function setBackgroundImage() {
  !document.querySelector('.div__active') || div.css({
    'background-image': `url(${grounds[++index % len]})`
  });
  window.setTimeout(setBackgroundImage, t * 41900)
})()
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #080c18;
}

.div,
.div__active {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://inteleqtika.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/5f8f7315229a10640a4319bb244ca199.jpg') center bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(1em);
}

.div__active {
  filter: none;
  animation: zoom 40s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  50% {
    transform: scale(2.5);
  }
}

.button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 40%;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 44px;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #001011, #4a82ad) 0 0/100% 1px no-repeat, linear-gradient(90deg, #4a82ad, #001011) 0 100%/100% 1px no-repeat, linear-gradient(0deg, #4a82ad, #001011) 0 0/1px 100% no-repeat, linear-gradient(0deg, #001011, #4a82ad) 100% 0/1px 100% no-repeat;
}

.button:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f1f1f1, #f1f1f1) 100% 0/4% 3px no-repeat, linear-gradient(0deg, #f1f1f1, #f1f1f1) 100% 0/3px 30% no-repeat, linear-gradient(90deg, #f1f1f1, #f1f1f1) 0 100%/4% 3px no-repeat, linear-gradient(0deg, #f1f1f1, #f1f1f1) 0 100%/3px 30% no-repeat;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px #fff) drop-shadow(0 0 6px #fff);
}

.button:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff, #ffffff) 100% 0/4% 1px no-repeat, linear-gradient(0deg, #ffffff, #ffffff) 100% 0/1px 30% no-repeat, linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff, #ffffff) 0 100%/4% 1px no-repeat, linear-gradient(0deg, #ffffff, #ffffff) 0 100%/1px 30% no-repeat;
}

.button:hover {
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
}

.button>.i__pause:before,
.button>.i__play:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 14px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -7px;
}

.button>.i__pause:before {
  width: 8px;
  height: 14px;
  border-left: 3px solid blue;
  border-right: 3px solid blue;
}

.button>.i__play:before {
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 14px solid cornflowerblue;
}

.button:hover .i__pause:before {
  border-left: 3px solid darkred;
  border-right: 3px solid darkred;
}

.button:hover .i__play:before {
  border-left: 14px solid darkred;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="sound"><source src="https://cdn.drivemusic.me/dl/online/Ro_TmDnjPpIZjo4G_On5JA/1584511306/download_music/2011/12/space-magic-fly.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<div class="div"></div><button id="button" class="button" onclick="playSound('sound')"><i class="i__play"></i>Начать путешествие</button>
```

Comment: Красиво вышло )

Comment: К уголкам можно еще прикрутить filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px #fff) drop-shadow(0 0 6px #fff);

Comment: Очень круто, как по мне.

Answer (score 7):

Вариант попроще, чем [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1095611/375080), но здесь есть момент, что надо угол наклона градиента подбирать вручную, если изменятся размеры кнопки.

```css
body {
  background: #111;
}

.button {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: rgb(192, 189, 189);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(15deg,#369,rgba(0,0,0,0),#369) 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px white;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.button:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px white;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Начать путешествие</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

### Вариант SVG + CSS

Анимация цвета рамки начинается при наведении курсора

Анимация уголков рамки начинается при клике на прямоугольнике.

```css
body {
background:#151515;
}
.container {
width:50vw;
 height:50vh;
}
#rect1 {
fill:transparent;
-webkit-transition: stroke .8s ease-in-out;
          transition: stroke .8s ease-in-out;
stroke:#94AAB8;
}
#rect1:hover {
stroke:#0932FF;
stroke-width:2;
cursor: pointer;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1"  viewBox="0 0 350 80">  

<defs>
    <filter id="gold_glow" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-20%" y="-20%" width="120%" height="120%">
           <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" result="blur5"/>
           <feColorMatrix result="red-blur" in="blur-merged" type="matrix"
                     values="1 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 1 0 0
                             0 0 0.2 1 0" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="red-blur"/>       
        <feMergeNode in="blur5"/>          
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>  
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

<rect id="rect1" x="5" y="10" width="340" height="50" />

   <rect id="rect2" x="5" y="10" width="340" height="50" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="40, 350 40, 350" stroke-dashoffset="20" filter="url(#gold_glow)" >
     <animate
       attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
       begin="svg1.click"
       dur="3s"
       values="20;70;70;410;410"
       fill="freeze"
       repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
  </rect>
   <text font-size="22px" x="50%" y="40" fill="white"  text-anchor="middle"  pointer-events="none">Начать путешествие </text>   
</svg>
</div>
```